# set custom location for a component in box layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a frame, inside this frame I have a panel with box layout, inside this panel I have 4 more panels.

```
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Basket Game");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        mainPanel.add(options);
        mainPanel.add(pname);
        mainPanel.add(info);
        mainPanel.add(gamearea);    

    mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setSize(600,600);
```

The form looks like this:

[image: form]

The first 3 panel is ok for me. But for the last panel (black one) I want to add some components with custom coordinates. But when I try to add them with custom coordinates:

```
basket.setLocation(500, 500);
gamearea.add(basket);
```

It goes directly top-center of the panel (coordinates doesn't affect it's location)

[image: second]

When I set `gameareI`s layout to `null` I can't see my label on the panel. I think I should do something extra for it. How can I do that?

Comment: Your main window is only 600x600.  With title bar, Options, Player name, and Info, y=500 is probably below the bottom of the pane.

Comment: Do you understand how a layout manager works? Do you understand the responsibility that the layout manager has? Do you understand who the reset of the API interacts with the layout manager? If you don't, then a null layout is not the choice you're seeking. In almost all cases, when you think you want a null layout, you probably don't. In those rare cases a null layout might be useful, a custom layout would result in far less issues and rework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your layout manager (`null`), nor with anything being left out.  The problem is simply 500x500 is outside of the bounds of `game area`.

```
public class NullLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(NullLayout::new);
    }

    NullLayout() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basket Game");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            JPanel strip = new JPanel();
            strip.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 50));
            strip.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Strip " + i));
            strip.add(new JLabel("Strip " + i));
            mainPanel.add(strip);
        }

        JPanel gamearea = new JPanel();
        gamearea.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.add(gamearea);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int x = i * 100, y = i * 100;
            JPanel basket = new JPanel();
            basket.setSize(200, 50);
            basket.setLocation(x, y);
            basket.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            basket.add(new JLabel("x = " + x + ", y = " + y));
            gamearea.add(basket);
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: Basket showing (0,0), to (300,300), but not (400,400)]

Notice that the `Basket` at 400,400 is not showing; it would be off the bottom of the game area.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always wrong to use a null layout. You should use a LayoutManager that helps place the components where you want them - especially useful if the user alters the size of the main frame. Use a GridBag or Mig layout.

If you absolutely insist on using a null layout, create a new GameArea class that extends JPanel, override its paintComponent() method and set the children's positions using child.setBounds(...). Be sure the first statement in your overridden method is `super.paintComponent(g);` .

Comment: A `null` layout is definitely allowed.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: Additionally, the user can't alter the size of the window, as `mainFrame.setResizable(false);` has been called.

Comment: @AJNeufeld it might be "allowed" but it s greatly discouraged and any time you might think you need it, you probably don't. The entire Swing API is written around the layout API and discarding throws an enormous amount of responsibility back on to the developer, which most aren't ready to deal with it

Comment: Don't, EVER, change the state of the UI from with the context of any paint method, this will set up a infinite loop of repaint requests which will consume your CPU cycles and make your UI unresponsive